# const char array in Objective-C has different value depending upon device

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, char, decode

In an app we are working on, there is a literal string we would like to keep secret so we have referenced it in the source as a `const char` array:

```
const char secret[] = {  0x63, 0x35, 0x4d, 0x58, 0x52, 0x32, 0x2c, 0x52, 0x53, 0x12, 0x3c, 0x74, 0x51, 0x53, 0x    69, 0x8a, 0x64, 0x12, 0x7f, 0x6e, 0x25, 0x64, 0x4e, 0x32, 0x23, 0x53, 0x12, 0x7b, 0x4c, 0x87, 0x64, 0x23, 0x41, 0x23, 0x56,     0x34, 0x6c, 0x23, 0x75, 0x5e, 0x56, 0x23, 0x65, 0x5b, 0x23, 0x75, 0x12, 0x65, 0x23, 0x76, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x53, 0x32a, 0x23, 0x54, 0x54, 0x21, 0x64, 0x32, 0x53, 0x13, 0x24, 0x32 };
```

(I've changed this so it doesn't match our secret :) )

We use `-[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]` to convert `secret` to `NSData`, then base 64 decode it and `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` it.

The problem is, on iPhone 5 & 4s converting the decoded data to a string fails.
Upon inspecting the contents of `secret` in the debugger, there are more characters than there should be.

Finally, copying the exact same literal to another `const char` and printing both in succession produces different results.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the devices in question are reading past the end of the array until they meet some kind of termination character. To stop this from happening, you need the final character in the array to be a newline.

```
$ echo -en "\n" | xxd -pu
```

shows us that `\n` as a hex is `0a`, so adding `0x0A` as the final element in the `secret` array literal will stop the OS from reading random memory. You also may want to make sure that the final `NSString` doesn't contain the newline character :)

### Update

The above fixed all problems on *Debug* builds, but on a *Release* build the same issue occurred so we replaced `0x0a` with `0x0` and both builds started working